# Easiest way to host your own LLM model from Huggingface?

Tags: environment

I’ve only used LLM API’s like OpenAI/Anthropic. How would I host my own model from somewhere like huggingface?

https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-180B For example, if I wanted to host this model and try to use it like I would use the paid LLM API’s, would the best way to host it is host it on HuggingFace with their inference API or using Amazon Sagemaker?

What is the easiest way to get started? What is the best way to host models like this at scale?

What are the best “free” or open-source models that we should be trying as a drop-in replacement for general LLM API’s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Easiest way to host your own LLM model from Huggingface?

https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui (23k stars) makes it convenient to host one's own LLM model "Its goal is to become the [AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) of text generation".

[image]

[image]

There also exists many git repos to make it easy to deploy LLM APIs.

> What are the best “free” or open-source models that we should be trying as a drop-in replacement for general LLM API’s?

See https://huggingface.co/spaces/HuggingFaceH4/open_llm_leaderboard for leaderboard and [How do open source LLMs compare to GPT-4?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/42064/4)